# Firebase Realtime Database Query Android

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a **Query** using **`orderByKey`()** as follows:-

```
private ChildEventListener childEventListener=new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            Log.d("DEBUG",String.valueOf(snapshot.getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };

DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/data");
Query query=ref.orderByKey();
query.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

Then when I add child to the `ref` in multiple devices using

```
ref.push().setValue("someValue");
```

I expect the `Log` inside the `onChildAdded()` method to print the children in a sorted order as seen in the database.But actually it prints the child added by the device itself first(Because listeners are fired immediately for local events),then sorts the other children.I think it beats the purpose of a query for sorting data.

Is there any way to get around this?

**EDIT:**
Suppose two devices are running the query shown above at the same time.
In device 1:

```
ref.push().setValue("I am device 1");
```

In device 2:

```
ref.push().setValue("I am device 2");
```

After this if i look at the database i see the following:-

```
data:
    -MD_hQfTlzo9fH03mbjT:I am device 1
    -MD_hQkXqB0nEZiGdy5A:I am device 2
```

So I expect the data to be ordered in the same way in the childeventlistener in both devices.In device 1, log output is:

```
I am device 1
I am device 2
```

But in device 2, the log output is:

```
I am device 2
I am device 1
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show in more detail what you expect/want the output to be, also showing the data in the database at the location of the query.  What you have right now is very abstract and difficult to imagine.

Comment: Edited to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

`onChildAdded` does not deliver the entire set of children under the node being queried.  After the query initially executes, `onChildAdded` will be invoked once for each child, **at the time of the query**, in the order specified by the query.  As long as the listener is still attached, it will receive another call to `onChildAdded` for each additional child that was added after that.  Again, it will not redeliver children that were previously added.

If you want the entire set of children to be delivered in order with every change to the node being queried, you shouldn't use `ChildEventListener`.  You should use a `ValueEventListener` instead.

Comment: I didn't mention anywhere that I want the entire data.

Comment: That's really your only option.  You can filter and order for what you want, and you'll always get everything.